# Discord.py Embed text file, get more results

Tags: discord.py

I'd like to send on a Discord bot a message embed but text is from another file. I did this way and it doesn't work:

```
bot.command()
async def gdc(ctx):
    """Wins GDC"""
    index1 = 0
    file = open("/home/plo/rkr/res_wins2", "r")
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        index1 += 1
        if index1 == 4: break
    message = line
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.description = message
    embed.title = title
    embed.colour = 0xF1C40F
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

However, it seems only one result goes out... Here is a part of my txt file:

```
Roi mouton: 9
tomate: 8
The_Portos: 8
```

And here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the value of line every loop in the for loop so you'll have to make a list of the lines

```
lines = []
with open("/home/plo/rkr/res_wins2", "r") as file:  # Use this to open and close the file
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        lines.append(line)
        index1 += 1
        if index1 == 4: break

embed = discord.Embed()
embed.description = '\n'.join(lines)
embed.title = title
embed.colour = 0xF1C40F
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```